# how i can make the drop down menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

today on the forum i found somebody talking about http://educationtechnologysummit.com/sponsors-a-partners.html

i need a drop down list as same as in the page.

how i can make my own who have effect all like this.

Comment: I don't see any dropdowns... Are you maybe referring to the animated menu on the page?

Comment: yeah menu on page drop down on top side.

Comment: Why *Steven Spielberg*? Having a personality deficit syndrome/disorder maybe? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the nice animated drop down menu, this website will help you build something very similar: http://www.queness.com/post/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial

This techniques is the simplest you can use and doesn't require a plugin to do it. Adjust animation speeds and other things that you need.

Unfortunately, the site you're referring to uses Mootools... :) But if you're into jQuery plugins you should be looking for [animated menu jquery plugin](http://www.google.com/search?q=animated+menu+jquery+plugin)